# Google sign in fails on my Android webview with Error 403: disallowed_useragent

Tags: android-webview, google-signin

How do I solve the error `Error 403: disallowed_useragent`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With WebViewGold, you can use the custom User-Agent "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/14F89 Safari/602.1" (without quotation marks) and the login works then.